# Dynamic Spark Structured Streaming: Handling Stream-Stream Joins with Changing

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I want to create a simple application using Spark Structured Streaming to alert users (via email, SMS, etc.) when stock price data meets certain requirements.

I have a data stream:
*data_stream*

However, I'm struggling to address the main issue: how users can modify the requirements (settings) whenever they wish.

I'm considering using another stream called *settings_stream* and then joining the two streams. But, I've realized that joining these streams will result in numerous unnecessary alerts to users. For instance, when users change settings, the new requirements will filter through all old price data (not just the last price), similarly when new price data arrives.

For example:

```
1.
Price | Timestamp
1     | 00:00
2     | 00:01
3     | 00:05
```

With new settings: price >= 1
=> 3 emails

2.

```
PriceRule | Timestamp
=1 | 00:01
=2 | 00:05
```

With the latest price: price = 1
=> 2 emails

How can I handle this situation? Or could you provide some solutions for this use case besides stream-stream join?

P.S.: My project must utilize Kafka and Spark Streaming/Structured Streaming.

Thank you all so much!"